# How to convert a file path to a blob in JavaScript without using fetch?

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron, blob, javascript-objects

I have a file path in a string:

```
"C:\Users\ajmal\Large\file.mp4"
```

I want to convert this file into a blob without using fetch or FileReader. Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe with XMLHttpRequest... Is there a reason you wish to do this?

Comment: Is this with NodeJS?

Comment: I'm creating a desktop app with electron js. While using fetch, it consumes a lot of system memory. @Samathingamajig

Comment: mp4 files tend to be quite big so storing a whole one in memory would consume a lot of memory no matter what mechanism you use to read it into memory

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem